# Extended Events session file truncated on server restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I have created an extended events session to capture login and logout information. The session is setup to store events to a file.
I understood that one of the advantages of using an event file (rather than a ring buffer) was that events history would be persistent across a restart. 
However it appears that a new event file is created when SQL Server is restarted and the history is lost. 
Is this expected? If so, what is the advantage of using a file rather than a ring buffer?

Comment: What is your `max_rollover_files` setting?

Comment: It is set to 1 because I want to keep all the data in one file. I know that limits the number of events I can store but the file is being truncated before it reaches the size limit.

Comment: I just tested this and it will not work. With restart SQL Server will still look at `max_rollover_files` setting and keep that many files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your question (and additional comments regarding your setting of `max_rollover_files` to 1:

> *However it appears that a new event file is created when SQL Server is restarted and the history is lost. Is this expected?*

**Yes - that is expected.**  When you restarted SQL Server all currently running extended events were terminated.  When you restarted SQL Server, a new extended event session started and your existing target file was replaced because you indicated you only wanted 1 file.  If you want to preserve extended event data stored in target files across server restarts, you will have to increase the `max_rollover_files` to something greater than 1.

`sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file (path, mdpath, initial_file_name, initial_offset)` has the capability of reading all extended event files in a the path referenced by *mdpath* if you specify `null` for the *initial_file_name*, so maintaining multple files should not be a problem.

Regarding the use of the Ring Buffer, take a look at why Jonathan Kehayias (*world renowned expert in SQL Server Extended Events*) [Hates the ring buffer](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/why-i-hate-the-ring_buffer-target-in-extended-events/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'll set max_rollover_files to a larger number and look at `sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file` to read from multiple files.   I think the last bit is the piece I was missing.   I think I had previously read Jonathan's article and had avoided using Ring Buffer for one or more of the reasons he described.